# Pig script running on MapReduce but not on Tez

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, tez

I am using version of Pig(0.16.0) and Tez version is 0.9.0. The pig script is running fine on MapReduce, but not with Tez. I had tried change tez-0.8.(3-5) still not work. Can this be a version mismatch problem? Please have a look at the logs:

```
ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.

org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.JobCreationException: ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJobCompiler.getJob(TezJobCompiler.java:137)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJobCompiler.compile(TezJobCompiler.java:78)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezLauncher.launchPig(TezLauncher.java:198)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:308)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1474)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1459)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1448)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:488)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:471)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:172)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:235)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:206)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:501)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:176)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.tez.dag.api.DAG.setCallerContext(org.apache.tez.client.CallerContext)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJobCompiler.getJob(TezJobCompiler.java:128)
        ... 20 more
================================================================================
```

Comment: have you checked that the tez libs are on the classpath?

Comment: @shainnif Thks, I has add tez libs to hadoop classpath in hadoop-env.sh. ```export TEZ_CONF_DIR=/home/hadoop/tez-0.8.5/conf
export TEZ_JARS=/home/hadoop/tez-0.8.5/lib
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:${TEZ_CONF_DIR}:${TEZ_JARS}/*:${TEZ_JARS}/lib/*```